# Dynamically load require.js modules under mixed base urls

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

We have an app using require.js, that at the same time allows extensions, and these extensions' js gets served from a different path. So in our config we have:

```
var require = {
  baseUrl : '/app/js/modules/'
}
```

But the extension is served from `/extension/foo-extension/js/modules/`.
Also, extensions are dynamic to the point that they inject some html into the page that uses a `data-module="foo/bar"` which we pick up on to load that module.

Ideally we'd be able to pass / set a context for require.js that scoped the following module loads to be within baseUrl `/extension/foo-extension/js/modules/`. As far as I can tell we would need to do `require('/extension/foo-extension/js/modules/foo/bar')` to load `foo/bar` from foo-extension.

Here is some pseudo code to imagine where we need to handle setting the path / context:

```
define(['some-dep'], function(SomeDep) {
    $.get('somepage', function(html) {
        var extension = html.data('extension'); // "foo/bar"
        var extensionBase = html.data('extensionBase'); // extension/foo-extension/js/modules/

        // This is where we need to readjust require to use the base path for any foo module
    });
});
```

Is there another solution to this part from going the absolute path route?

Answer (score 4):

requirejs.config() can be called later, at any time, and the loader will merge the configs together. So it should be enough to wait until you know what you want to use for the paths config for 'extension', then set it via another requirejs.config() call, then do the loading of the extension with that path.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you'd want to use the ["paths" configuration option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths). Example:

```
var require = {
  baseUrl : '/app/js/modules',
  paths   : {
    'extension' : '/extension/foo-extension/js/modules'  
  }
};
```

Then you could simply call `require('extension/foo/bar')` to load `/app/js/modules/extension/foo-extension/js/modules/foo/bar.js`

Comment: Notice the *dynamic* bit here. I can't use paths because this happens way after my configuration is set up. If paths were interpolated somehow I could use `/extension/{extension}/js/modules/` though.

Comment: "Ideally we'd be able to pass / set a context for require.js that scoped the following module loads to be within baseUrl..." This is exactly what the paths option does. If you need a dynamic, server-side solution, may I suggest posting a description of what is happening server-side?

Comment: It is to set predefined paths. We pick up on this path from data-attributes in the markup that is loaded via ajax requests on a later time. This is way after we have spat out the require.js config with our paths. I'm updating the question with some more pseudo code ...

Comment: superp, i did not know you could set a partial path as well, this helped me out a lot !